# Problems with responsive menu displayed on iPhone (z-index?)

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've created a site for a client and it loads great... except on an iPhone.

I've used emulators on my Windows PC, my Android phone, Safari on Windows... all is ok. But on a iPhone it gets wonky.

Here's the issue:

In responsive mode (less than 1024px) when you load the menu, there should be "Close" and "Menu" along with other menu items. However on the iPhone, "Close" and "Menu" do not load. It's like the menu items are being overlaid by a background image that I am using.

I used Z-Index and it now it displays fine on Safari on Windows but not on the iPhone.

Can someone give insight into the problem and a possible fix?

Beta site is at www.conxis.com/nmp

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and just moved the menu lower so it would not be overlapped by the background image.

It's not a solution, just an admission of defeat.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the code. The problem seems to be all of the hidden inputs before .menuTable. They're interfering with the top menu buttons.

```
<div class="screen">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s1" id="sub1a-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s1" id="sub1b-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s1" id="sub1c-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s1" id="sub1d-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s1" id="sub1-close">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2a-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2b-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2c-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2d-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2e-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s2" id="sub2-close">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s3" id="sub3a-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s3" id="sub3b-open">
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="s3" id="sub3-close">
    <div class="menutablet">
        <ul>
            <li class="m-close"><label for="menu-close" title="close menu"></label>Close</li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="dinein.html">DINE IN</a></li>
            <li><a href="carryout.html">CARRY OUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="catering.html">CATERING</a></li>
            <li><a href="cheesecakes.html">CHEESECAKES</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code is to make the menu shift from the left / to the right when opening and closing the menu. Disabling the code has no affect on the issue.

Comment: It appears that the problem is z-index is being used, which iPhone does not recognize.

Comment: iPhone uses the Webkit rendering engine, so it definitely supports z-index. It's likely that by changing/removing z-index you brought the menu to the top, which fixed your issue.

Comment: I wound up having to move the menu down 81px so it would not be overlapped by the background image that stays in place for the sliding effect.